# Can you check for a DB2 license in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, db2, db2-400

I've written a WPF app in C# (4.5) and it connects to a DB2 server.  I want to know if there's a way to check the local machine for a valid DB2 license and display a warning if it's not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not an api to access the license manager in DB2. However, you have two options:

- Execute the db2licm and parse the output.
- Analyse the nodelock file in the license directory where db2 is installed (/opt/ibm/db2/V10.5/license/nodelock)

Answer (score 1):

You have to run the `db2licm` command to check the DB2 license.

[Click here](http://docs.starquest.com/Supportdocs/techStarSQL/StarSQLODBC/Programming/SQ054_CSharp.NETQuery.shtml) to see how to run DB2 commands in C#.